# HP Pavilion x360 Convertible, installing Linux, endless IRQ and logging loop

Tags: linux, resources, hp, irq

When installing a Linux OS (e.g. Mint) from a live cd or USB stick, editing /etc/default/grub does not solve the problem. You can add or edit a line like
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
in /etc/default/grub, then running update-grub (which internally uses grub-mkconfig) will transfer that to /boot/grub/grub.cfg .

But that becomes effective only after a reboot, and when you reboot a Linux live session (i.e. without having installed anything to hard disk yet), the live stick will reinstate its own Grub settings again, so you have the interrupt looping problem yet again.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution (I thought of it by accident, yesterday, I wish the idea had come up earlier!): In the grub menu that the booted ISO, or Ventoy (or wherever it comes from) presents to you, press the letter e! That's e for edit. Then you can add pci=noaer there, just before the live session starts! And the looping problem will be gone!

This allowed me to finally install Linux Mint 21.1 Vera on my HP Pavilion 360 laptop.

Before that, there was a process constantly doing interrupt 123, AND two processes that logged that 'error' (a harmless error, automatically fixed) to two different log files! In the live environment, there is a squashfs file system, that actually resides in RAM, and which is limited in size. So after a minute or so, on a very slow computer because the processors were kept busy all the time, it ran out of 'disk' space, and the computer got stuck and became completely unresponsive and unusable. Impossible to do the install I wanted to do.

After the "e for edit" trick, the problem was gone, I could install the OS to harddisk, and THEN I still had to edit /etc/default/grub, run update-grub, and reboot, to make the solution permanent. I felt so relieved!

Comment: Is kernel 6.2.9 affected? If it is, please report this bug to bugzilla.kernel.org/

Comment: Interesting question. I tested Alpine 3.17 and Linux Mint 21.1, both with kernel 5.15. Kernel 6.2.9 is quite new, looks like I'd have to compile it myself. Never did that before, although I probably can. Are there any distributions that have that kernel already, that I could test on the hardware in a live session? Arch maybe? Will look.

Comment: I tried Arch Linux 2023.04.01 which uses kernel 6.2.8. It works in KVM/QEMU, but I can't get it to run bare metal via Ventoy. I get error messages which are immedately overwritten by a "Press any key to continue".

Will now try Manjaro 22.0 with kernel 6.1

Comment: Yes, the looping occurs in Manjaro as well. systemd-journal takes 90 to 100% of CPU capacity, and irq/123-aerdrv about 25%. The system remains quite responsive, though. I find no disk filling up. Perhaps systemd-journal only logs in RAM, or in a rolling file?

Output of uname -a:

Linux manjaro 6.1.19-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Mar 13 12:59:35 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: But isn't this more like a hardware / firmware / chipset problem? Could it actually be fixed in the Linux kernel? Is it therefore really useful to report it to the kernel maintainers?

Comment: Fedora has it but it's a whole different distro.